# Компилятор даёт ошибку С2109

Tags: c

Возникла данная ошибка, при задании создать динамически массив.

**Алгоритм программы:**

1. Создаём массив 6х6.
2. Используем авто заполнение массива  с помощью **rand%36**.
3. Выводим сам массив.
4. Конец.

**Сам код:**

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{

    int *a;
    int i, j, n=6, m=6;
    a = (int*)malloc(i*j*sizeof(int));
    printf("Array[6][6]:\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 36;
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно возникла ошибка:

```
a[i][j] = rand() % 36;
printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
```

Гуглил, были похожие примеры, но эти варианты решения проблемы для моего кода не подошли.

Answer (score 3):

Во первых у вас в начале не определены значения i, j
А вы делаете на основе них malloc. Думаю там имелось ввиду `malloc(n*m*sizeof(int))`

Проблема в том, что при обращении со скобками компилятор просто не понимает размерность массива по первому аргументу.
проще всего так:

```
        *(a+i*n+j) = rand() % 36;
        printf("%4d", *(a+i*n+j));
```

Comment: Ну, или определять `a` как `int **a`, чтобы пользоваться `a[i][j]`.

Comment: @andy.37  Нет, int **a будет указателем на массив указателей. тогда ему придется делать отдельные malloc на каждую строку массива, помимо malloc на первый уровень

Comment: да `malloc` придется переписывать. Но пользоваться `a[i][j]` ведь можно будет?

Comment: @andy.37 Да, можно конечно :) Просто я такие варианты не рассматриваю, потому как привык экономить память везде где можно. А тут будут накладные расходы на сами указатели (4 или 8 байт на строку, в зависимости от архитектуры) + накладные расходы менеджера памяти. Да и результирующий код будет: как минимум с двумя `lea` или аналогами для загрузки адресов из памяти и потом уже обращение. Цлочисленная арифметика в регистрах быстрее отработает.